# Rails view rendering nested layouts - named yield not working while unnamed yield does work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rendering, yield

Non-working Code:

```
# application.html.erb, BASE layout
<html>
<head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</head>
</html>

# _pwa.html.erb, SPECIFIC layout
<div class="container">
  <%= yield :main_content %>
</div>

# _partial.html.erb, ACTUAL body
<% content_for :main_content do %>
  <h1>Test</h1>
<% end %>

# view.html.erb, actual view file that links everything together
<%= render layout: "layouts/pwa" do %>
  <%= render "partial" %>
<% end %>
```

When `view.html.erb` is rendered by the controller, I would like the output html file to look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

But the `<h1>Test</h1>` is not actually there. On the other hand if I remove the named yield, and just replace with a regular yield, it does work. I.e., the code below does generate the correct output above:

Working Code:

```
# application.html.erb, BASE layout
<html>
<head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</head>
</html>

# _pwa.html.erb, SPECIFIC layout
<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>

# _partial.html.erb, ACTUAL body
<h1>Test</h1>

# view.html.erb, actual view file that links everything together
<%= render layout: "layouts/pwa" do %>
  <%= render "partial" %>
<% end %>
```

But I do want figure out how to get the named regions working, because the actual `pwa` layout is a bit more complicated, and I'd like to do something like the below:

```
# _pwa.html.erb
<div class="container">
  <%= yield :main_content %>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <%= yield :secondary_content %>
</div>

# _partial.html.erb
<% content_for :main_content do %>
  <h1>Test</h1>
<% end %>
<% content_for :secondary_content do %>
  <h2>Second</h2>
<% end %>
```

Edit, I actually have an iterator like so:

```
<%= render layout: "layouts/pwa" do %>
  <% @pages.each do |p| %>
    <%= render "partial/#{p}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Make sure the content_for objects are being created before their call.

Comment: change posisitons yield and content_for

Comment: thanks! not sure what you guys mean though, `content_for` and `yield` so not sure how to do any position changing to make sure `content_for` objects are created before `yield`

Comment: @james, Try to this one: `render partial: 'partial', layout: 'layouts/pwa'`

Comment: ah ok well I have a bit of hidden context here, I actually have an iterator (see above edit), which is why I don't really want to do it that way, because then the layout gets rendered multiple times. @fongfan999 I guess for me it's also helpful to know why the named yield doesn't work, but the non-named yield does work?

Comment: @james, Wait wait!! You're using `partial layout`, but wrap `iterator`? Sorry, I didn't understand. What was your expected result?

Comment: where is your `iterator`?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, I made an answer below taking elements of what I learned. This definitely breaks MVC but hopefully the answer makes sense. Would love your thoughts/comments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback! What I ended up doing is below. This accomplishes:

1. Have a progressive "app" feeling on a website WITHOUT redirects (i.e., JS hide/show content simulates moving from page to page) for X pages. I think this was the hardest part, because it breaks MVC... but an important trade off in my case
2. There is a SINGLE layout rendered for all X pages, yet some content on this layout will vary depending on which page we're in
3. Content on X pages is further shareable across other progressive flows of Y pages

**View file hierarchy**

```
> views
  > layouts
    - _pwa.html.erb # single layout for all steps
  > orders
    > optionA
      - _place_A.html.erb # unique content for a shared view file that is further shared across options
      - flow_layout.html.erb # iterator that pulls in views from the various pages relevant to this option from shared_views folder

    > optionB
      - _place_B.html.erb # unique content for a shared view file that is further shared across options
      - flow_layout.html.erb # iterator that pulls in views from the various pages relevant to this option from shared_views folder
    > shared_views
      > views
        - _open.html.erb # unique content for a given page
        - _place_A.html.erb # unique content for a given page
        - _place_B.html.erb # unique content for a given page
      > layouts
        - _place.html.erb # similar content for a page that's different than other pages (i.e., open and place are different pages), but with elements shared across options (i.e., place_A and place_B have a lot of sharing)
```

**Code**

```
<!-- shared layout file: layouts/_pwa.html.erb -->
<%= render "/layouts/navbar", progress_counter: @pages.count %>
<div class="container-fluid zero-padding  non-navbar">
  <div class="row-fluid "> 
    <%= yield %> <!-- main content, varies for each of X pages -->
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid troubleshooter_title">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h4 class="cursor-point underline text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span> <%= troubleshooter_title %> <!-- named content varies for each of X pages -->
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= yield :troubleshooter_content %> <!-- named content varies for each of X pages -->
</div>

# Orders Controller file for 2 set of steps (optionA vs optionB)
# as implied below, "place_A" and "place_B" are VERY similar, with a few tweaks
def optionA
  # second element of inner array stores other info not relevant to this answer here
  @pages = [
    ["open"],
    ["place_A"],
  ]
  render "#{action_name}/flow_layout"
end

def optionB
  @pages = [
    ["place_B"],
  ]
  render "#{action_name}/flow_layout"
end

<!-- flow_layout as rendered by controller -->

<!-- optionA/flow_layout.html.erb -->
<%= render layout: "layouts/pwa", locals: {troubleshooter_title: "Having trouble?" } do %>
  <% @pages.each do |p| %>
    <%= render "shared_views/views/#{p[0]}" %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<!-- optionA/flow_layout.html.erb -->
<%= render layout: "layouts/pwa", locals: {troubleshooter_title: "How it works" } do %>
  <% @pages.each do |p| %>
    <%= render "shared_views/views/#{p[0]}" %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<!-- above note one important fact, I wanted the troubleshooter_title to CHANGE between optionA & optionB -->


<!-- shared_view partials -->
<!-- shared_views/views/_open.html.erb -->
<!-- first div goes into main yield -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h1>Open the door</h1>
</div>
<% content_for :troubleshooter_content do %>
  Try pushing instead of pulling
<% end %>

<!-- shared_views/views/_place_A.html.erb -->
<!-- given the fact that place_A and place_B are very similar, there's a nesting here of a place layout file that holds all the commonalities. the minor differences are placed with the optionA view folder itself -->
<%= render layout: "shared_views/layouts/place" do %>
  <%= render "optionA/place_A" %>
<% end %>

<!-- shared_views/views/_place_B.html.erb -->
<!-- same as above -->
<%= render layout: "shared_views/layouts/place" do %>
  <%= render "optionB/place_B" %>
<% end %>

<!-- place layout -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h1><%= yield %></h1>
</div>
<% content_for :troubleshooter_content do %>
  <%= yield :nested_troubleshooter_content %>
<% end %>

<!-- optionA/_place_A.html.erb -->
Place A: put on table
<% content_for :nested_troubleshooter_content %>
  Table is directly in front of you 
<% end %>

<!-- optionB/_place_B.html.erb -->
Place B: put on rug
<% content_for :nested_troubleshooter_content %>
  Rug is to the right of you 
<% end %>
```